# How to echo custom styles in css format?

Tags: customization, css

I'm usually do dynamic-style.php file for making dynamic css codes from theme options, shortcode, customizer and all others.

But, you may already know it'll slow down our site speed. I would highly target to have custom style format in our header or footer echo like within : style tag.

Also, searching for hover option within our shortcode it self? I done that by adding fields. But, little confusion about how to echo hover within our style="" itself. So, it should be fine if each shortcode have unique class name and we can add :hover there.

Like :

```
.element-class-9123 {color: white;}
.element-class-9123:hover {color: black;}
```

If you've better method, please let me know. It would really helpful for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are asking. Would you please try to clarify?

Comment: I want, button normal and hover background color and text color. That is need to make it from php code. I've added WordPress shortcode fields.

Like : [button text_color="black" text_hover_color="white"]

Is it possible with php code? Or just have look below brian comment : He mentioned unique id in php code. Which is awesome! But don't know how to use it within our page style tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`uniqueid()`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_uniqid.asp) from php. It'll generate unique id for your css selector.

Or if you use any WordPress core pages like : archive, tags, category pages, please refer following article: [9 Ways to Set Dynamic Body Ids via PHP and WordPress](https://perishablepress.com/dynamic-body-class-id-php-wordpress/)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, i've looked but it's little hard to use within our shortcode. Iike i want that all css codes in : <style> tag in our page header or footer. Is is possible?